# Removing punctuation and tabs with sed

Tags: bash, macos, sed, tr

I am using the following to remove punctuation, tabs, and convert uppercase text to lowercase in a text file.

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g' $HOME/file.txt | sed $'s/\t//g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Do I need to use these two separate `sed` commands to remove punctuation and tabs or can this be done with a single `sed` command?

Also, could someone explain what the `$` is doing in the second `sed` command? Without it the command doesn't remove tabs. I looked in the man page but I didn't see anything that mentioned this.

The input file looks like this:

```
Pochemu oni ne v shkole?
Kto tam?
Otkuda eto moloko?
Chei chai ona p’et?
    Kogda vy chitaete?
    Kogda ty chitaesh’?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single `sed` with multiple `-e` expressions, which can be done as below for `FreeBSD sed`

```
sed -e $'s/\t//g' -e "s/[[:punct:]]\+//g" -e 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/' file
```

With the `y` quanitifier for,

```
[2addr]y/string1/string2/
      Replace all occurrences of characters in string1 in the pattern 
      space with the corresponding characters from string2.
```

If in `GNU` sed, `\L` quantifier for lower-case conversion should work fine.

```
sed -e $'s/\t//g' -e "s/[[:punct:]]\+//g" -e "s/./\L&/g"
```

`$''` is a `bash` quoting mechanism to enable  [ANSI C-like escape sequences.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings)

Comment: @I0_ol: Can you output `sed --version`? It worked fine on `GNU sed`

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X

Comment: The `\L` escape is not portable.  A portable replacement is `y/ABC/abc/` but you don't have access to ranges (portably) so you have to enumerate the whole alphabet, upper and lower case.

Comment: I installed `gsed` from Homebrew. This works now `gsed -e "s/[[:punct:]]\+//g" -e "s/./\L&/g" -e $'s/\t//g' ~/file.txt` Thanks for your help.

Comment: @I0_ol: Refer my update, it is expected to work on `Mac OS X`

Comment: what is the meaning of first `$` just after the `-e` and before first quote ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: Please refer the embedded link I have included in my update, It is a `bash` quoting way to interpret escape sequences like `\t`